# Is there a function in SSIS to extract functionality from a package to be added to other packages?

Tags: ssis

I just added error handling functionality to an SSIS package that I am upgrading, and I need to add this same error handling to about 30 more packages.  Is there a way to extract the error handling control flow, parameters, variables, etc. so that I can easily add them to the rest of the packages?

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 and SSIS 15.0.

I found a bunch of articles on BIML, but it looks like that is only for creating new packages.  I am aware that copy and paste exists, but I would like to try to find a solution that is easy to apply across future packages as well as the current packages being updated.  Apologies if this question has already been asked, I searched, but I'm not sure that I even really know what search terms would be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Biml is an excellent choice for creating consistent packages going forward. Even if you're only generating empty packages with error handling logic, that's a pattern and that's the power of Biml.

With the change to BimlExpress and the now free ability to reverse engineer packages, an approach could be to reverse engineer the packages to Biml. That would all be static tier but you'll need to select all and then in a new BimlScript file, add the error handling like so

```
<#
foreach(AstPackageNode apn in this.RootNode.Packages)
{
    if (!apn.Events.Where(x => x.EventType==EventType.OnError).Any())
    {
        AstTaskEventHandlerNode onError = new AstTaskEventHandlerNode(null);
        onError.EventType = EventType.OnError;
        onError.Name = "OnError";
        // TODO: add tasks and such
        apn.Events.Add(onError);
    }
    
    //WriteLine(apn.GetBiml());
}
#>
```

Once that's looking good, you right click on everything at once and generate packages.

A non-Biml approach is going to test your C# (or VB.NET) skills. I've not touched this type of SSIS dev in more than a decade but the concept will remain the same. https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/10/what-packages-still-use-configuration.html

You'll need to find all the SSIS packages. For each one of those, use a reference to the DTS Runtime application to load it. Then look at the package's Events collection and if there isn't an OnError, you're going to have to add one to the collection and then add all the associated tasks, configure them and then save.